# restoring an edited photo received from dif. phone

Tags: photoshop-elements

My wife keeps sending me edited pictures, thinking I can't undo the edits. Is there any way, or any software I can use to see the original image? Some photos are pictures merged into another. Some have been edited blacking out certain aspects of the photo. I have tried to take the edit out, with little success.

Comment: "My wife keeps sending me edited pictures of her infidelity... is there any way... to correct this injustice?" – Have you considered **DIVORCE**?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot 'revert an edit' without the original image & edit path to revert through.

In broad terms -

You can put a smiley over someone's face, but you cannot restore the original face without the original photo.

You can selectively remove objects from photos with smart enough software, but no software is smart enough to be able to put it back.

You can remove a background & replace it with another - but again, no software is smart enough to be able to put the original background back in.